# How to separate an array with JavaScript for styling purposes

Tags: javascript, html, css, json, fetch-api

I have included the whole array within a single div at the moment however I would still like to display the array but separately so that I could style `"date"` `"title"` and `"text"` individually.

My JSON folder:

```
[
{
    "date": "Example Date",
    "title": "Example Title",
    "text": "Example Text" 
},
{
    "date": "Example Date",
    "title": "Example Title",
    "text": "Example Text"
},
{
    "date": ""Example Date",
    "title": "Example Title",
    "text": "Example Text"
}
]
```

My HTML:

```
<div id="myData"></div>
```

Fetch API:

```
        fetch('example.json')
        .then(function (response) {
            return response.json();
        })
        .then(function (data) {
            appendData(data);
        })
        .catch(function (err) {
            console.log('error: ' + err);
        });

    function appendData(data) {
        var mainContainer = document.getElementById("myData");
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            var div = document.createElement("div");
            div.innerHTML = data[i].date + data[i].title + data[i].text;
            mainContainer.appendChild(div);
        }
    }
```

So basically how can I have 3 div's instead of one with each individual div showing the `"date"`, `"title"` or`"text"` for styling instead of one `div` with all 3 items in?

I tried to do 3 functions to separate `"date"`, `"title"` and `"text"` however it only shows the last array item. for example the "text" information. I am new to JavaScript.

Comment: Those aren't arrays. They're objects. You're doing it right. Why not just add markup to your `innerHTML` statement?

Answer (score 0):

Replace the innerHTML line with

```
div.innerHTML = '<span class="date">' + data[i].date + '</span>' + 
                '<span class="title">' + data[i].title + '</span>' +
                '<span class="text">' + data[i].text + '</span>' ;
```

And writing css for those date, title, text classes will do the job.

Here's a working [pen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/QXWYqK?editors=1111)

Answer (score 0):

Then just make 3 divs per array element. You're making one.

```js
fetch('example.json')
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(appendData)
  .catch(console.error)

function appendData(data) {
  const mainContainer = document.getElementById("myData");
  for (const {date, title, text} of data) {
    const div = document.createElement("div")
    div.append(
      textDiv(date, 'date'),
      textDiv(title, 'title'),
      textDiv(text, 'class')
    )
    mainContainer.append(div)
  }
}

function textDiv(text, cls) {
  const div = document.createElement("div")
  div.textContent = text
  if (cls) div.className = cls
  return div
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [for-in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) to iterate over the properties of your inner object. That way, you don't need to know which object keys to expect in advance.

```js
fetch("https://api.myjson.com/bins/r9hhx")
  .then(function(response) {
    return response.json();
  })
  .then(function(data) {
    appendData(data);
  })
  .catch(function(err) {
    console.log("error: " + err);
  });

function appendData(data) {
  var mainContainer = document.getElementById("myData");

  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    const item = data[i];
    var outerDiv = document.createElement("div");
    outerDiv.className = `item outer`;

    for (var key in item) {
      var innerDiv = document.createElement("div");
      innerDiv.innerHTML = item[key];
      innerDiv.className = `item inner ${key}`;
      outerDiv.appendChild(innerDiv);
    }
    mainContainer.appendChild(outerDiv);
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.item {
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.date {
  background: rgba(0, 121, 0, 0.1);
}

.title {
  background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.text {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.1);
}
```

```html
<div id="myData"></div>
```